# Escape "\" backslash from dataweave for csv output Mule

Tags: csv, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

CSV output is generated from java Map in Dataweave,
Output response adds "\" to every "," present within the values.
All the map values are added inside the double quotes, ex: map.put('key',"key-Value");

**Response Received** :

Header1, Header2

1234,ABC \,text

7890,XYZ \,text

**Expected Response**  :

Header1, Header2

1234,ABC ,text

7890,XYZ ,text

**Header2** should contain "ABC,text" as value  without quotes ""

Tried using %output application/csv escape=" ", but this adds extra space to each blank space in the values i.e if the value is "ABC XYZ" then output is "ABC  XYZ" (2 spaces in between)

Any suggestion will be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Embedded commas in data in a comma separated value file **must** be escaped or there is no way to tell those values apart from field separators.  If you want some way to have the commas in your CSV file without escaping them, then you need to use a separator other than a comma.

You **Expected Response** as shown would not be valid, as you have a two field header, but data lines that would be interpreted as having 3 fields, not 2 fields, one with an embedded comma which is what the data has and is shown in the **Response Received** table.

Comment: using separator="special_character" like "?","|" etc...and then replacing it with "," seems to be the way to get the desired result...

Comment: It is also perfectly legal, if the target application is able to handle it, to use something other than a comma as the separator in a CSV file.  Many commercial software packages, such as Excel, can handle Tabs as a field separator.  Many custom packages cannot.  If the embedded commas are not essential to the data, you can simply have DW remove them, or replace them with another char, such as a dash which would not be seen as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same scenario, where we have comma in the data itself, like in your case Header2 .

To solve the issue, I've just added below

%output application/csv **quoteValues=true**

above solved my problem, and we got the expected output.